# How to try to start a service only if it isn't running? (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

I know I have to count how many instances are running:

```
ps x | grep apache2 | wc -l
```

result if it's running: `2`, or else: `1`

I also know there is a command called `test` that I could use to perform the verification, but I don't know how to use `test` with `wc`

Comment: W​h​ich distro?

Comment: "/sbin/service apache2 status" will show if the service is start or stop.

Comment: @Ignacio ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The startup scripts on most Linux distributions handle this, by saving the **Process ID** of the service (daemon) when they launch it.

These PIDs are typically stored in `/var/run/`. For example on my system Apache2 stores it original or parent process ID (useful for pre-forked processes) in `/var/run/apache2.pid`. So you can then send signals such as `SIGHUP` or `SIGSTOP` to the process to signal either a configuration reload or to stop the service (daemon).

One note to help with your `ps ax` style process searching is to use a little trick to escape the grep's regular expression pattern used for matching, such that it doesn't match itself. E.g. `ps ax | grep [a]pache2 | wc -l`

`man test` gives you the basics of the `test` command. For simple tasks in shell scripting, it best to avoid being dependent on which shell you are using. Normally for [basic scripting](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Main_Page), writing scripts targeting the Borne Shell (`/bin/sh`) is recommended, as this tends to be the most popular lowest common denominator.

```
#!/bin/sh

RC= `ps ax | grep [a]pache2 | wc -l`

if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
  kill -SIGSTOP `cat /var/run/apache2.pid`
fi
```

Comment: What a clever idea to use `grep [a]pache2`! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with bash, you can do it with conditional [checks](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html#sect_07_01_01):

```
#/bin/bash
num="1"
if [ $num -eq "1" ]; then
        echo "got 1"
fi

if [ $num -eq "2" ]; then
        echo "got 2"
fi
```

Comment: how to make `num` equal to `ps x | grep apache2 | wc -l` ?

Comment: @Jader, I've included an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (( $(ps x | grep [a]pache2 | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
    do_something
else
    do_something_else
fi
```

or

```
case $(ps x | grep [a]pache2 | wc -l) in
    0)
        do_zero_thing
        ;;
    1)
        do_one_thing
        ;;
    *)
        do_default_thing
        ;;
esac
```

The square brackets used in that way in the `grep` command suppresses the `grep` itself from being included in its own output. This will make the process count 0 if apache isn't running.